# Large size of main.js file in Angular 2 app build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I build an app using `angular-cli@0.0.39`. It's conversion of simple angular 1 application. 
The problem is the size of `main.js` file which is more than 800KB.
I see that the file contains (probably)all angular 2 modules.

I built by `ng build --environment=production` command.

Am I missing something or that is correct size of the file?

Comment: AFAIK the Angular team is busy making tree-shaking work.

Comment: im getting it somewhere to 700kb...i guess we will have to wait and watch

Comment: juristr.com/blog/2016/06/ng2-getting-started-for-beginners search for "tree shaking"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, I saw a video about it from ng-conf thous I thought that it is implemented and I missed something in build process

Comment: I don't think this is already available. There are lots of related commits since a while and I guess they will ship something soon. Didn't have a very close look at all the RC2 changes yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently i have checked few projects that use angular with webpack and it seems that currently this is minimum size of the application.

angular2-webpack-starter (raw size report):

```
@angular: 1.98 MB (85.5%)
core-js: 178.45 KB (7.53%)
rxjs: 53.99 KB (2.28%)
zone.js: 52.72 KB (2.23%)
```

817kb after minification.

---

Using `webpack --json` command and `webpack-bundle-size-analyzer` tool.